# Sending a UDP datagram in an Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a "server-less chat" app using the Ionic framework.  The concept is pretty simple and has been done before, but I'm doing it for a school project.  I'm pretty new to Ionic and Javascript in general.

Here's the problem I'm running into:

I'm trying to create a socket and send a UDP datagram (IP multicast) out over the LAN.  I've found some Angular.js modules that seem to have some socket functionality, but it appears that they're all geared toward connecting to a server.

I've found this node.js module that appears to do what I want, but I don't know how to get it recognized inside Ionic.  I'm sure I'm just missing an include or something.  I have node.js installed and have searched through the directories, but haven't been able to find anything referencing the UDP/Datagram module.

https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Any ideas?